# AmazingListView Adapter Not Downloading?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-listview, android-adapter

I need to work on Android ListView. I want to [Download this code from here](http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/source/checkout).
I was unable to download this code. but it give me this message

```
    # Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.
    svn checkout http://android-amazing-listview.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ android-   
    amazing-listview-read-only
```

How to download  this code ?
If any one give me other link of this or can mail me then it will be great help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to download this **Tortoise svn** from here http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html

Then **create new folder and right click on that folder -> SVN checkout -> paste your url here** in URL repository

for ex: http://android-amazing-listview.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Comment: or any other [SVN Client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Subversion_clients)

Comment: +1 @zapl:Thanks for good suggestion,i have just given: For example